# What is "hellostepfunc1" in the serverless documenation for setup AWS stepfunctions?

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-step-functions

In these documentation from the serverless website - [How to manage your AWS Step Functions with Serverless](https://serverless.com/blog/how-to-manage-your-aws-step-functions-with-serverless/) and [GiTHUb - serverless-step-functions](https://github.com/horike37/serverless-step-functions), we can find this word `hellostepfunc1:` in the `serverless.yml` file.  I could not find reference to it. I dont understand what is it, and I can't find any reference to it, even after the State Machine was created into AWS.

If I delete it I get the follow error

```
Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'role' in myStateMachine
```

But if I change its name for `someName` for example I have no error and the State Machine will works good.

I could assume it is only an identifier but I not sure.
Where can I find reference to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite specific to the [library](https://github.com/horike37/serverless-step-functions) you are using and how it names the statemachine which is getting created based upon whether the `name:` field is provided under the `hellostepfunc1:` or not.

Have a look at the testcases [here](https://github.com/horike37/serverless-step-functions/blob/master/lib/deploy/stepFunctions/compileStateMachines.test.js) and [here](https://github.com/horike37/serverless-step-functions/blob/master/lib/naming.test.js) to understand better.

In-short a .yaml like

```
stateMachines:
    hellostepfunc1:
        definition:
            Comment: 'comment 1'
            .....
```

has name of statemachine like `hellostepfunc1StepFunctionsStateMachine` as no name was specified.

Whereas for a .yaml like

```
stateMachines:
    hellostepfunc1:
        name: 'alpha'
        definition:
            Comment: 'comment 1'
            .....
```

the name of statemachine is `alpha` as you had name was specified.

Comment: Ok, If I got it is only a substitute, in case name: is not there. But I can change for any name. I mean it could be `hellostepfunc1:` or `hellostepfunc2:` or `anynameiwant3:`. Is it correct?