# What is "hellostepfunc1" in serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless, aws-step-functions

Someone has made a similiar question, but the answer is unclear to me and I would like a bit more detailed answers.

[What is "hellostepfunc1" in the serverless documenation for setup AWS stepfunctions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51714795/what-is-hellostepfunc1-in-the-serverless-documenation-for-setup-aws-stepfuncti)

What is "hellostepfunc1" in all the serverless tutorials? Can I rename it to anything else I want?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can name the steps whatever you wish.

The JSON file specifies which step is the Start Step.